# where to change Coupon code is not valid error message

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

we created coupon code and we wanted it should not applicable only for **particular category**.

so we used this condition as in image. its working fine.

[image]

but we are getting error message as below.

**Coupon code "123456" is not valid.** [not real coupon code ]

we want to change this error message as `coupon code not applicable for this category`.

We are using [Magento Hackathon promocode error message](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_PromoCodeMessages) module

we checked in extension code & in **app/locale/en_us/csv** files , there is no error message matching present to match  above error message.

we found above message in these 2 files **app/locale/en_us/ Mage_checkout.csv** , **Mage_xmlconnect.csv** .we changed here also but its not working for us.

Please tell me where i need to chnage those error message.

```
public function validate($couponCode, $quote)
    {
        $this->_quote = $quote;

        try {
            /** @var Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon $coupon */
            $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);

            return;
        }

        // no coupon
        if (!$coupon->getId()) {
            Mage::throwException($this->_formatMessage('Coupon code does not exist.'));
        }

        /** @var $rule Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule */
        $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($coupon->getRuleId());

        $this->_validateGeneral($rule, $coupon);
        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('checkout/promocodemessages/include_conditions')) {
            $this->_validateConditions($rule);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show custom error messages on cart page
Hi in this article i will try to tell you all about how to show custom error messages or popups on cartpage

in the below folder 
**app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php**

near about **line 537** you will find code something like this

```
 else {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(
                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode))
                    );
                }
```

which contains a error message for wrong coupon code apply

which i have change to

```
else {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(

                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode))
                    );
                    $myValue = 'Hello World';
                   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyvalue($myValue);

                }
```

in this i have make use of magento sessions , i have set a session as setMyvalue
for the wrong code apply and than check the value of this in cart file

cart file path  under 
**yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml**
i have retrieve the session value something like

```
 getMyvalue(); ?> 

do something:: you can do anything here like show your html ,js popups.....

do somethindo something:: you can do anything here like show your html ,js popups.....
```

thats it ......

Comment: Welcome to mse, we need stars like you..... You saved my day.....  Thanks a lot... I like your profile name :-)