# Disable Coupon code for specific category in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

How to restrict **coupon code** functionality for **specific category** of products in **magento 1.9**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login your admin . open your promotion code rules. setup category condition

[image]

Comment: thanks Shorabh Kumar Gupta for your response.. if i give this condition from core files of coupan it can be work that or not ? or if it is work pls guide me.

Comment: because i want to restrict this coupon code for permanent base that's why i want to help from you.

Comment: @kajol we can first overwrite coupon core files . put there your category filter. please do code only specific coupon

Comment: ok @Shorabh thanks and want one more help from you i want change coupon code error message to custom message and i was change this error message through this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125674/where-to-change-coupon-code-is-not-valid-error-message?rq=1   but no chnage in frontend after clear cache and index resizing.

Comment: @kajol i think you try to csv

Comment: Try update app/design/frontend/youtheme/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv.

Comment: k i will try this

Comment: i try all this csv file which you mentioned and also in link after that no changes in frontend.